# Does editing applicationhost.config file restarts IIS 7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

Does editing applicationhost.config file restarts IIS? I want to edit the applicationhost.config on the production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, changing the file itself doesn't cause an AppDomain recycle like editing web.config or machine.config does.

However, some settings, like application pool defaults, global settings or http modules will cause an AppDomain recycle.

Just adding settings in location tags to the bottom or doing general settings won't cause an AppDomain recycle.  All site specific changes will, at the most, impact the one site only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to add 
<mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" /> in <staticContent> section. Does it cause a restart?

Comment: I had to test to confirm, but yes, making a change to the global staticContent section is one of the changes that will cause an appDomain recycle.  So, it's best to make the change off-hours, or make it for just the site that needs it.